# Can't figure out how to print out all the integers in my dictionary value list

Tags: python-3.x

Curious if there is any way to do something similar to this.

```
Dictionary = {"item":1,"item2":[1,2,3,4]}
for keys,values in Dictionary.items():
    if values == list():
        print(values[0:3])
```

With the resulting outcome of

1
2
3
4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is:

```py
Dictionary = {"item": 1, "item2": [1,2,3,4]}

for values in Dictionary.values():
    if type(values) == list:
        for item in values:
            print(item, end=' ')
```